# Application not calling function inside WCF swrvice

Tags: .net, wpf, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

We have a WCF service , which provide details about the versions of an installed application.
This WCF service is installed in different machines.Our application calls all the machine WCF services and check the version in all machines.
To check whether the function is calling , we have added a code which logs some information into a text file.But when we are calling the WCF function with our application no log is being written into that text file. 
Our assumption is firewall is blocking the application from accessing the service, so it is not going inside that function. We cannot set the firewall off on that machine also.
So we have added an inbound rule in Firewall with TCP as Protocol and 808 as port number.

Please somebody help me on this and let me know if any more information is required.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would suggest to initially run the service which you have created on your own machine , just to be sure that the service is getting hit. You can as well "Attach the Process" on the port which your service is running just to check if your Application to service call is successful.
2. If YES , then the next step is to setup the service in another machine and ensure if the endpoints are correct in your Application . Request you to please take the service endpoint of the remote machine and check it in the machine where the Application is running.
3. If that is also running fine then just disable the Firewalls on both the machines and try .

Do let me know in which step it is failing so that we can guide you better .